# convert point layer data to line layer in ArcMap

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, esri

I'm a bit of a GIS newbie, but we have a database of point data (already set up to be accessible as a feature set), and need to be able to see it as lines.

We've attempted a number of approaches to this outside of Arc (the most recent two being a stored procedure or a dedicated app; both for batch processing).  While either approach was technically possible, we were unable to make either sufficiently performant to be useful.

So now we're looking to attack this with a different approach.  Namely, some form of dynamically generating just the needed line feature set (i.e.: with just the needed lines, rather than all possible ones in the DB).  And I've done some research, but am unable to find a way to do this, particularly in light of the fact that the Arc server is updating the features on a regular interval (and is doing it via a standard SQL query).

Can anyone point me in a general direction of a feasible approach?

We're using ArcServer (and ArcMap), C# for development, and SQL Server on the back end.

Thanks much.

Comment: Are you essentially trying to "connect the dots"? How do you have the data organized so it knows which dot should connect to which?

Comment: The connecting part is basically solved; I have code for that (though it might need to be refactored a bit).  The question is how to get the code started.